# How to set AngularJs attributes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have my angular directive `draggable1` as follow:

```
    angular.module('test', []).
    directive('draggable1', function($document) {


        return function(scope, element, attr) {
            var startX = 0,
                startY = 0,
                x = 0,
                y = 0;
            element.css({
                position: 'relative',
                cursor: 'pointer'
            });


            element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
                // Prevent default dragging of selected content
                event.preventDefault();
                //elementDragged = this;
                startX = event.screenX - x;
                startY = event.screenY - y;
                $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
            });

        /*  
        element[0].addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.innerHTML);
        elementDragged = this;
            });
        */  

            function mousemove(event) {
                y = event.screenY - startY;
                x = event.screenX - startX;
                element.css({
                    top: y + 'px',
                    left: x + 'px'
                });
            }

            function mouseup() {
                $document.off('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.off('mouseup', mouseup);
                //comparePositions();
            }




        };
    });
```

When I predefined this:

```
<li id="something" draggable1>Element One</li>
 it works completely fine, and I am able to drag my component.
```

But When do the similar thing in code, it does not work,

```
<li id="something">Element One</li>
document.getElementById("something").setAttribute("draggable1",true)
```

And my `element` does not move. How can I set this `attribute` in a proper way?

Comment: What's your goal here?

Comment: when the user clicks a certain button, this item would become draggable.

Comment: your issue is more likely that when you add the element the script has already collected all of the draggables, you need to re-run that bit.

Comment: also you need to use this line to make this work <li id="something" draggable1>Element One</li>
Without that directive in there this will not work.  Cuz directive needs to know which element you want it to be draggable.

Comment: yes, how exactly can I re-run that part?

Comment: one thing you can do is that you can have a bigger directive outside of whatever elements you want draggable and use $compile function to make elements draggable, but I don't really see the point for it.

Comment: Not modifying the DOM manually is kinda the cardinal rule of AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of AngularJS's inbuilt directive `ng-if` to check for the condition and execute it conditionally. This way you can apply your directive in a conditional way.

*Example:*

```
<div ng-if="{some_condition}">
    <ul>
      <li id="something" draggable1></li>
   </ul> <!--Execute the directive on the basis of outcome of the if condition-->
</div>
```

*Other example*

You can pass a scope variable to the directive and check it if it's true / false or other condition, and then apply your code. Your goal will be to to this inside the directive. Hope this will help you.